# Issues placing image at the left of TextView generated dynamically

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have created a TextView dynamically and added it to a linear layout. The TextView is supposed to have an icon on its left. I have added the icon and wanted the TextView to be in the center.

**The code:**

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(getContext());
        valueTV.setText(richPost.getPostCreateDate());
        valueTV.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0, 0);
        valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        llInner.addView(valueTV);
```

**The output:**

[image: output result]

I want the image to be right before the text and want to remove the huge gap in between. The text is in the proper place, I want the image to be centered beside the text. Where am I going wrong? What should I do?

Comment: tried with sample its working fine.i think richPost.getPostCreateDate().trim() may be help to u

Comment: @RamBabuPudari it was of no use, still icon sticks to the left

Comment: what your textView dimens?

Comment: @yshahak did not set any, I think its getting the default width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make yoúr TextView wrap its content by adding this to your code:

```
valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Additionally, to get the icon and text centered in the LiniarLayout, which you can do by adding this to the LinearLayout:

```
yourLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
yourLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I have created the parent linear layout programatically. I cannot set your suggestion to the XML

Comment: Result is, text also sticks to the left, beside icon

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by `TextView` layout parameters. It seems to me that in your case width of TextView is `match_parent`, so the `drawableLeft` position is defined by left side of `LinearLayout`.

Here is simple example to feel the difference

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:text="some text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and try the same layout with `match_parent` width of `TextView`